# Why won't jqGrid DatePicker display when I click or focus on textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, datepicker

I have created a working jqGrid that does everything that I need it to but I am stumped as to the problem here. When I open an add row or edit dialog I can add/edit any field at my leisure but when I focus on, or click the button next to, the begin date or edit date boxes, the datepicker does not display. I have even copied exactly what I have seen on the trirand.net examples.

Here is my markup.

```
<trirand:JQGrid runat="server" ID="addGoalsGrid" AddDialogSettings-Modal="true" OnRowAdding="addGoalsGrid_RowAdding"
            OnRowDeleting="addGoalsGrid_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="addGoalsGrid_RowEditing"
            SearchDialogSettings-MultipleSearch="true">
            <Columns>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="GoalID" PrimaryKey="True" Visible="false" Searchable="false" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="BeginDate" Editable="true" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:d}" Width="70" EditType="DatePicker" EditorControlID="beginDateTextBox" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="EndDate" Editable="true" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:d}" Width="70" EditType="DatePicker" EditorControlID="endDateTextBox" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="GoalName" Editable="true" EditType="TextBox">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="75" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                    <EditClientSideValidators>
                        <trirand:RequiredValidator />
                    </EditClientSideValidators>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="WeeklyGoal" Editable="true">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="75" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                    <EditClientSideValidators>
                        <trirand:RequiredValidator />
                    </EditClientSideValidators>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="GoalComplete" Editable="true" EditType="CheckBox"
                    EditDialogColumnPosition="2" EditDialogRowPosition="3" HeaderText="Goal Complete" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Task1" Editable="true" Visible="false" EditType="TextBox"
                    HeaderText="Step 1">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="75" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="T1EstimatedHours" Editable="true" Visible="false"
                    EditType="TextBox" HeaderText="Estimated Hours" EditDialogColumnPosition="2"
                    EditDialogRowPosition="6">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="3" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="T1Complete" Editable="true" Visible="false" EditType="CheckBox"
                    HeaderText="Complete" EditDialogColumnPosition="3" EditDialogRowPosition="6" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Task2" Editable="true" Visible="false" EditType="TextBox"
                    HeaderText="Step 2">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="75" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="T2EstimatedHours" Editable="true" Visible="false"
                    EditType="TextBox" HeaderText="Estimated Hours" EditDialogColumnPosition="2"
                    EditDialogRowPosition="9">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="3" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="T2Complete" Editable="true" Visible="false" EditType="CheckBox"
                    HeaderText="Complete" EditDialogColumnPosition="3" EditDialogRowPosition="9" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Task3" Editable="true" Visible="false" EditType="TextBox"
                    HeaderText="Step 3">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="75" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="T3EstimatedHours" Editable="true" Visible="false"
                    EditType="TextBox" HeaderText="Estimated Hours" EditDialogColumnPosition="2"
                    EditDialogRowPosition="12">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="3" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="T3Complete" Editable="true" Visible="false" EditType="CheckBox"
                    HeaderText="Complete" EditDialogColumnPosition="3" EditDialogRowPosition="12" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Task4" Editable="true" Visible="false" EditType="TextBox"
                    HeaderText="Step 4">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="75" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="T4EstimatedHours" Editable="true" Visible="false"
                    EditType="TextBox" HeaderText="Estimated Hours" EditDialogColumnPosition="2"
                    EditDialogRowPosition="15">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="3" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="T4Complete" Editable="true" Visible="false" EditType="CheckBox"
                    HeaderText="Complete" EditDialogColumnPosition="3" EditDialogRowPosition="15" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Task5" Editable="true" Visible="false" EditType="TextBox"
                    HeaderText="Step 5">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="75" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="T5EstimatedHours" Editable="true" Visible="false"
                    EditType="TextBox" HeaderText="Estimated Hours" EditDialogColumnPosition="2"
                    EditDialogRowPosition="18">
                    <EditFieldAttributes>
                        <trirand:JQGridEditFieldAttribute Name="size" Value="3" />
                    </EditFieldAttributes>
                </trirand:JQGridColumn>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="T5Complete" Editable="true" Visible="false" EditType="CheckBox"
                    HeaderText="Complete" EditDialogColumnPosition="3" EditDialogRowPosition="18" />
            </Columns>
            <ToolBarSettings ShowEditButton="true" ShowRefreshButton="True" ShowAddButton="true"
                ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowSearchButton="True" />
            <AddDialogSettings Modal="True" LoadingMessageText="Please Wait..." SubmitText="Add Goal"
                Resizable="false" Width="900" />
            <EditDialogSettings Modal="true" LoadingMessageText="Please Wait..." SubmitText="Submit Changes"
                Resizable="false" Width="900" />
            <ToolBarSettings ShowEditButton="True" ShowAddButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True"
                ShowSearchButton="True" ShowRefreshButton="True">
            </ToolBarSettings>
            <SortSettings InitialSortColumn=""></SortSettings>
        </trirand:JQGrid>
        <trirand:JQDatePicker DisplayMode="ControlEditor" runat="server" ID="beginDateTextBox" DateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" ShowOn="Both" />
        <trirand:JQDatePicker DisplayMode="ControlEditor" runat="server" ID="endDateTextBox" DateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" ShowOn="Both" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use formatter and unformat function for the column where calender is required check [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter)